# How to connect SAP BW to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jdbc, jupyter-notebook, odbc, hana, sap-bw

I don't know the SAP world well and I need your advice.
I need to connect some procedures located on SAP BW (SAP HANA DB) with a data science platform containing Jupyter Notebooks. The goal is to exploit SAP BW data from Jupyter Notebooks for analysis.

I found on internet various solutions to do this:

- connection between the two environments using connectors such as 'JDBC' or 'ODBC';
- connection via api/web services exposed by SAP BW and read by Jupyter Notebook;
- using SAP-specific libraries in Python such as 'pysapbex';
- connection between SAP BW and Jupyter Notebook using 'i-OhJa';
- connection using 'OLAP BAPIs'

I would like to ask you what you think is the best way to extract data from SAP HANA via jupyter notebook, so would appreciate any advice to achieve the goal!
Thank you so much!